# Hide original path with blob

Tags: javascript, blob

I'm creating a video club system and wanted to protect the original path of the movies using blobs like YouTube does, but I've been doing a Google search and I do not find how does that make someone can give me a north?
PS: All the movies of the video club are in .MP4

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on Stack Overflow please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and if not already done, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

There is a huge misconception here...

#### Youtube doesn't *hide* the url of the video files.

If the final URL is a blobURI (`blob:https://www.youtube.com...`) it is because what the MediaElement displays is actually a [MediaSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource) Object.
They do fetch different ranges from different encodings and compose the data to be presented on the fly. This way, they are able to downgrade the quality if they see they didn't had time to fetch the upcoming part of the video.
But all the requests are clearly visible in your dev-tools' Network panel and anyone willing can actually compose themselves a full file.

So once again, this is not a piracy protection whatsoever.

Also note that since blobURIs are URIs that do point to the local memory of the web-browser if you can display anything from a blobURI, it means it's already too late to try to protect it (since already downloaded and available in memory).